# How to delete a product from m_product table in openbravo

Tags: openbravo

how to delete a particular product from m_product table in openbravo , Because it has triggers and are interlinked with other tables

Answer (score 1):

I don't think doing a SQL delete is a good choice, since there are some tables related with a particular product (like accounting information).

At application level, if the product is already referenced from another table (like an Order), you wont be able to delete it.  However, you can always de-activate the record, achieving a logic deletion of the product.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete using database queries, it will automatically prompt you the linked items where it is being used with the table names. You can remove the dependencies there. If you want to automate it, refer the linked items implementation in openbravo and use that as a base to find out where it is linked and remove them.

Thanks,
Shankar

Answer (score 0):

You may use following options

1) Instead of deleting entry you may consider marking product as inactive or discontinued, so that product will not be available/visible on other windows and reports

2) Delete all linked items first, then delete product entry from UI

3) If you are deleting, using SQL statements - first delete all references(linked tables data) or temporarily turn off triggers and delete